# site footer on large screens - filling the space

Tags: css, footer

on large screens my footer doesn't sit at the bottom of the page leaving a white "bar" along the bottom (color of the page background).

I'm aware of sticky footers etc but due to using absolute positioning on elements in the footer these techniques make the rest of the footer go awry. I have now added an empty div below the footer directly before  and set its min height to 100% and background colour to match that of the footer (black) however it does not do anything - only a set height in pixels will do anything but i want it to be dynamic so it fills the space if it is there whether its 10px of space or 500px of space.

Has anyone got an for a work around?

Comment: Without a link or any code we can't help

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do a sticky footer, make your `body` background color the same color as your footer, then set the background of your content area to white. This gives the appearance that the footer extends to the bottom of the page, no matter the size of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't use the 'absolute' style of footer positioning, it's a terrible solution.

Oddly enough, Twitter Bootstrap has the easiest example of how to implement a sticky footer - it's a technique that's been around for ages:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

The method is simple. Put a wrapper div around all your code, except for the footer. 
If you refer to the source of that link, you'll see a wrapper with an id of wrap.
If you then examine the css for the above:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/sticky-footer.css

Just copy the sticky footer styles section and adapt for your site. The key part of this is the footer height value matches the margin and padding values of the wrapper element.